# ¿Cómo guardo los valores de un observable en un array?

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0

Necesito hacer un search bar para mi aplicación pero la lista que creo la obtengo de un servicio que lo guarda en un observable y no sé como obtener los datos para llamar a los métodos de la search bar (a lo mejor guardando en un array los nombres).

El Json que guardo en mi observable es el siguiente:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "GoParken",
        "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": "PHP",
            "icono": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/php-4096-black.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "IONIC",
            "icono": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/ec/17/ddec173bbaa672d3a45f6a41b9891eb3.png"
        }
        ],
        "g_index": 98
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Mercado de Ideas",
        "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": ".NET",
            "icono": "http://getsetwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/net.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "IONIC",
            "icono": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/ec/17/ddec173bbaa672d3a45f6a41b9891eb3.png"
        }
        ],
        "g_index": 98
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Wowlandia",
        "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": "PHP",
            "icono": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/php-4096-black.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "COCOS 2D",
            "icono": "http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/cocos2d_banner.png"
        }
        ],
        "g_index": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Dilo con señas",
        "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": "PHP",
            "icono": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/php-4096-black.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "IONIC",
            "icono": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/ec/17/ddec173bbaa672d3a45f6a41b9891eb3.png"
        }
        ],
        "g_index": 18
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "nombre": "Bandala",
        "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": "PHP",
            "icono": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/php-4096-black.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "IONIC",
            "icono": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/ec/17/ddec173bbaa672d3a45f6a41b9891eb3.png"
        }
        ],
        "g_index": 18
    }
    ]
```

Y lo obtengo de la siguiente manera con un provider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

/*
  Generated class for the KpisProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class KpisProvider {

  private url: string = 'https://private-anon-3cb8931ec8-kpisapi1.apiary-mock.com/api/Projects';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello KpisProvider Provider');
  }

  getProjects() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res  => res.json());
  }

  getUserDetails( projectID ){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + projectID).map(res  => res.json());
  }

}
```

Y hasta ahorita llevo lo que muestra la siguiente imagen pero falta darle funcionalidad a la search bar

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener los valores de tu Observable suscribiéndote a él:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    projects = [];

    constructor(private kpisProvider: KpisProvider) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.kpisProvider.getProjects().subscribe(
          (res: any) => this.projects = res,
          (err: any) => console.error('Ha ocurrido un error al tratar de obtener los proyectos.')
        );
    }

}
```

O bien puedes recorrer el Observable apoyándote en el pipe async:

Typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    projects: new Observable<Array<any>>();

    constructor(private kpisProvider: KpisProvider) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.projects = this.kpisProvider.getProjects();
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects | async">
  <p>{{ project.nombre }}</p>
</div>
```

### Actualización

Si la intención es recoger el valor del input search y con el realizar la petición asíncrona de datos y repoblar el listado de proyectos, puedes referenciar el elemento y tener otro array para mostrar los proyectos filtrados.

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar #search></ion-searchbar>
```

Typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    projects: new Observable<Array<any>>();
    projectsFound: new Observable<Array<any>>();
    @ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;

    constructor(private kpisProvider: KpisProvider) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.projects = this.kpisProvider.getProjects();

        Observable.fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'keyup')
          .debounceTime(150)
          .distinctUntilChanged()
          .subscribe(() => this.searchProject(this.search.nativeElement.value));
    }

    private searchProject(value: string): void {
        if (value) {
          this.projectsFound = this.kpisProvider.getUserDetails(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sí, de hecho recorro el observable mediante el pipe, pero me duda es de como obtengo los valores para usar una barra de busqueda. Ya que todo los ejemplos que veo usan solo un array de cadenas.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener el value del input search y realizar la petición con ese value?

Comment: @dddenis hola amigo, como podría hacer si el observable es una respuesta de una api y quiero recorrer el un arreglo que viene ahí, el arreglo viene como una propiedad del objeto, algo asi: {propiedad1; valor, propiedad2: valor, arreglo[ {p1: v1, ... }, {p1: v1, ....} ]}  ? en el objeto de la pregunta el arreglo ya viene listo, aquí el arreglo viene dentro de un objeto, no se si me explico.